# UPDATE, INNER JOIN PHP to MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this MySQL command that updates values from one table to the other. The command works great on MySQL but can't seem to get it to run in PHP. I want to be able to run this command every time I refresh a page

MYSQL Command Example

```
UPDATE stock
INNER JOIN item USING (name)
SET stock.price = item.price, stock.quantity = item.quantity
```

in PHP it looks something like

```
$innerJoin="SELECT * FROM storeDB" . 
           "UPDATE stock" .
           "INNER JOIN item USING (name)" .
           "SET stock.price = item.price, stock.quantity = item.quantity";

mysqli_query($conn, $innerJoin);
```

When I refresh the page, I look into MySQL only to find the values on stock remain the same, not updated.

A bit rusty on PHP and MYSQL..

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why is your query string written in PHP different from the one you run directly on the database? It should be the same. Also pay attention to space characters when concatenating strings in PHP.

Comment: You have no spaces in your query.  It looks like this: `UPDATE stockINNER JOIN item USING (name)SET stock.price = item.price, stock.quantity = item.quantity`

Comment: Well initially I tried using the exact same query but seems as if the dots make an invalid syntax in PHP. So I tried playing with quotes since my other SQL queries that I run successfully have quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$innerJoin = "UPDATE stock INNER JOIN item USING (name) SET stock.price = item.price, stock.quantity = item.quantity";
mysqli_query($conn, $innerJoin);
```

You should use the same query string...

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have tried using the same query with quotes but seems as if the dots create an invalid syntax in php. At least I think does based on the color. So I tried playing with double quotes since my other PHP to MySQL queries have double quotes such as

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE `quaintity` = '0'";

Non the less I did try that way and no luck. I also tried the MySQL Command in phpMyadmin and no luck either.